# Join multiple time series tables in a performant View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple devices reporting in 1 second data to a SQL database through 3rd party software. Each device's data gets written to its own table in the form of `{TimeStamp, Measurement}`.

I need to combine these in a frequently-accessed view. My current solution is this (shown with 5 tables):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[combined]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        allTS.[TimeStamp] As 'TimeStamp'
        ,dbo.[device1].[Measurement] As 'Device1' 
        ,dbo.[device2].[Measurement] As 'Device2'
        ,dbo.[device3].[Measurement] As 'Device3'
        ,dbo.[device4].[Measurement] As 'Device4'
        ,dbo.[device5].[Measurement] As 'Device5'
    FROM 
    (SELECT dbo.[device1].TimeStamp FROM dbo.[device1] UNION
      SELECT dbo.[device2].TimeStamp FROM dbo.[device2] UNION
      SELECT dbo.[device3].TimeStamp FROM dbo.[device3] UNION
      SELECT dbo.[device4].TimeStamp FROM dbo.[device4] UNION
      SELECT dbo.[device5].TimeStamp FROM dbo.[device5]
     ) allTS
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[device1] ON allTS.[TimeStamp] = dbo.[device1].[TimeStamp]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[device2] ON allTS.[TimeStamp] = dbo.[device2].[TimeStamp]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[device3] ON allTS.[TimeStamp] = dbo.[device3].[TimeStamp]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[device4] ON allTS.[TimeStamp] = dbo.[device4].[TimeStamp]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[device5] ON allTS.[TimeStamp] = dbo.[device5].[TimeStamp]
GO
```

The devices should keep common timestamps, however, this is not guaranteed, so I added the UNION subquery. This has (so far) been performant up to 13 tables with over 1,000,000 records each, but not sure how much longer that will scale.

Is there an easier or more performant way to do this time series join?

Comment: A possible improvement would be to materialise the union of the timestamps as its own indexed view instead of querying it each time.

Comment: A bona fide query can be optimized. A view -- like the one you are presenting -- is only part of a query. Please include the specific query you want to optimize.

Comment: @Stu I don't believe I can create an index on a view with the UNION operator. So not sure if that would help. Thoughts?

Comment: @TheImpaler The query is a basic time series query `SELECT * FROM combined WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN ___`. The view was to prevent me from having to pass massive queries from an unrelated API.

Comment: @kale How big [in average] do you expect that timestamp range be, percentage-wise?

Comment: @TheImpaler Generally in the range of minutes (ie 30 to 300 records), but some historical retrievals of 3 or 4 days worth (200,000-300,000 records). Percentage wise mostly 1-2%.

Comment: @kale If the percentage is below 5% your strategy is good, assuming you add an index on the `Timestamp` column of all your tables. It'll be better if the percentage is lower (below 1%). If your percentage is higher, you can consider using a materialized indexed view instead.

Comment: @kale yes you're right - I've used index views but never needed on a union of multiple tables. As an alternative idea, could you materialise a permanent table of all possible timestamp values - similar to a numbers/tally table - and use this as the source to outer-join to? Possibly rebuilding this regularly eg daily based on the min relevant timestamp and max safe future timestamp?

Comment: @TheImpaler Timestamps are indeed indexed in the individual tables. As performance is good for current use case, I’ll leave as is unless another suggestion comes up.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Of course ideally you wouldn't store the data like that. Instead of a table per device you would have a column to identify the device.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a `full join` using `left join`s.  That might be a good way to go, but I would start with the query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(d1.Timestamp, d2.Timestamp, d3.Timestamp, d4.Timestamp, d5.Timestamp) As TimeStamp,
       d1.[Measurement] As Device1,
       d2.[Measurement] As Device2,
       d3.[Measurement] As Device3,
       d4.[Measurement] As Device4,
       d5.[Measurement] As Device5
FROM dbo.[device1] d1 FULL JOIN
     dbo.[device2] d2
     on d2.Timestamp = d1.Timestamp FULL JOIN
     dbo.[device3] d3
     on d3.Timestamp = COALESCE(d1.Timestamp, d2.Timestamp) FULL JOIN
     dbo.[device4] d4
     on d4.Timestamp = COALESCE(d1.Timestamp, d2.Timestamp, d3.Timestamp) FULL JOIN
     dbo.[device5] d5
     on d5.Timestamp = COALESCE(d1.Timestamp, d2.Timestamp, d3.Timestamp, d4.Timestamp)
```

You still want indexes on `(Timestamp, Measurement)` -- or at least on `(Timestamp)` -- in each of the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `Timestamp` is indeed indexed on each individual table. Would this method scale to large tables well? It'll definitely be quite verbose with my real-life case of 13 tables: `d13.Timestamp = COALESCE(d1.Timestamp ......... d12.Timestamp)`.

Comment: @Kale . . . You would need to test it on your data.  I could just imagine that SQL Server better optimizes `full join` as opposed to `union `/`left join`.  But you would need to test that on your data.